# Bypass stop job timer

Tags: shutdown, 15.10, reboot, systemd, timeout

Is it possible to make ubuntu shutdown right away instead of counting to 1.30min then shutdown. PS: It is a script that is running that gives the message.[image]

Comment: I didn't try it out but maybe setting [DefaultTimeoutStopSec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man5/systemd-system.conf.5.html) in  `/etc/systemd/system.conf` can solve this?

Comment: Worked!! Post as answer to get reward

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I already mentioned in comments, setting [DefaultTimeoutStopSec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man5/systemd-system.conf.5.html) in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` should solve this problem.

Comment: Cannot award before another 22 hours. We just have to wait

Comment: This is a workaround, A solution would be to figure out why systemd can't stop whatever it needs, and fix it. Apparently, it has been years, and no one is interested, so mean while users just tell systemd to go kill itself after 10 seconds.

Comment: Is there no keyboard shortcut that can be used on a one-off basis to bypass the offending job during shutdown? While adjusting configuration files is great, it doesn't help with the immediate problem of a spurious 90-second (or longer, depending on configuration) delay, not to mention that changing config files is irrelevant for cases like recovery filesystems that do not persist changes.

Comment: You can actually use keyboard shortcuts to bypass the problem... sorta. You can use sysrq, here's a guide, it's for manjaro but works the same on ubuntu. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-reboot-turn-off-your-frozen-computer-reisub-reisuo/3855